# What is wrong in my python implementation of Stochastic gradient descent on Boston House Pricing database?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am a beginner in machine learning. I am trying to implement Batch Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithm on Boston Housing price data in Python. I think I am following the algorithm correctly for linear regression but I am getting very large values for weight vectors & intercept.
Could anyone pleasehelp me?

```
import numpy as np
r=1 
diso=0.0 
intercep=0 
x=np.random.normal(0.0,1.0,13)    
for c in range(50):
    sums2=0
    batch=traindat.sample(n = 100)
    batch1=batch.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)
    batch2=batch['PRICE']        
    predtargs=(batch1.iloc[:,0:13].dot(x)+intercep)
    listofsums_weights=[]

    for j in batch1.reset_index(drop=True):
        sums=0
        for i in range(len(predtargs)):
            sums=sums+(-2*(batch2.reset_index(drop=True).get(i)-((predtargs.reset_index(drop=True).get(i))))*batch1.reset_index(drop=True)[j][i])
        listofsums_weights.append(sums)
    for i in range(len(predtargs)):
        sums2=sums2+(-2*(batch2.reset_index(drop=True).get(i)-((predtargs.reset_index(drop=True).get(i)))))
    newx=[]
    intercep=intercep-r*sums2
    for m in range(len(x)):
        newx.append(x[m]-(r*listofsums_weights[m])) 
    r=r/2    
    disn=np.linalg.norm(np.array(x)-np.array(newx))
    x=newx
    if int((diso))==int((disn)):
        break
    diso=disn 
print('Final weight vector') 
print(x) 
print('Final intercept') 
print(intercep)
```

Here 'r' is the learning rate.All the feature values are normalized. Euclidean Distance between the weight vectors is decreasing but the individual values are very high.

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming problem

Comment: But when I use SKlearn sgd regressor the weight vectors values become lower.So I am not getting what am I doing wrong in the code.